# How to empty a column via the phpmyadmin editor?

Tags: phpmyadmin

The following editor popped up when I clicked edit in the table screen:

[image]

I only see the Delete and Update button. How can I empty the column, say, `company_info_html`?

Comment: What do you mean by "empty the column"? If you mean make every row in the table have `NULL` as the value, then do: `UPDATE company_master SET company_info_html = NULL` (that will do EVERY row). You could also do the same but set them to `""` (an empty string). Is that what you want?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot empty the content of a column directly via phpMyAdmin, by dragging a column name like you did. The screen you are showing is to help you type SQL commands. The UPDATE statement suggested by alexchenco would do the job.